C# cannot use .Any() when build Expression for querying with EF core
I'm trying to build an Expression<Func<T, bool>>:
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateAny<T, TAnother>(
        Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TAnother>>> collectionPropertyExpression,
        Expression<Func<TAnother, bool>> anyPredidate
    )
    {
        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), collectionPropertyExpression.Parameters.Single().Name);
        var anyMethodInfo = typeof(Enumerable)
            .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
            .Single(m => m.Name == "Any" && m.GetParameters().Length == 2)
            .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(TAnother));
        var anyCallExpression = Expression.Call(
            anyMethodInfo,
            collectionPropertyExpression.Body,
            Expression.Lambda<Func<TAnother, bool>>(anyPredidate.Body, anyPredidate.Parameters.Single())
        );
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(anyCallExpression, param);
    }

This is how i use it:
public async Task<IActionResult> Tests()
   {
        /*I want it returns something like:
            a => a.ReceivedNotifications.Any(noti => noti.Status == NotificationStatus.Read)
        */
        var exp = ExpressionHelper.CreateAny<Account, AccountNotification>(
            a => a.ReceivedNotifications,
            noti => noti.Status == NotificationStatus.Read
        );
        logger.LogInformation("{0}", exp); // a => a.ReceivedNotifications.Any(noti => (Convert(noti.Status, Int32) == 2))
        return Ok(await unitOfWork.Accounts.GetAsync(expression: exp)); // error here
    }

and I got an error: 

System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'a' could not be
translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See
https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I need to know why I have an error here and is there any solution for this?

Thank you in advance.

What are you trying to do in the first place? What you posted is how you think the problem can be solved, not the problem itself. You can use .Any() in a LINQ query when it makes sense, so what's the purpose of CreateAny ?

And where's the EF code? Or LINQ? EF neither has nor needs a GetAsync method or a "Unit-of-Work". DbContext already is a multi-entity Unit-of-Work. You can use any valid LINQ expression in context.Accounts.Where(...).FirstAsync() to retrieve the first entity that matches the expression. Right now, we can't tell what the relevant code is or why it failed

Are you trying to run context.Accounts.Where(acc=>acc.Notifiations.Any(noti=> noti.Status == NotificationStatus.Read)).FirstAsync() ? If so, why use Reflection instead of just using the expression acc=>acc.Notifiations.Any(noti=> noti.Status == NotificationStatus.Read) ?

For Entity Framework, you don't want Enumerable.Any, but Queryable.Any

@HansKeﬆing, you are wrong here. Navigation properties are IEnumerable. And EF Core reads just metadata.

I recommend leveraging the compiler for reflection rather than manually searching methods and combining result expressions.
public class ExpressionHelper
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> CreateAny<T, TAnother>(
        Expression<Func<T, IEnumerable<TAnother>>> collectionPropertyExpression,
        Expression<Func<TAnother, bool>> anyPredicate
    )
    {
        Expression<Func<IEnumerable<TAnother>, Func<TAnother, bool>, bool>> anyTemplate =
            (collection, predicate) => collection.Any(predicate);

        var entityParam = collectionPropertyExpression.Parameters[0];

        var resultExpression = anyTemplate.Body;

        // replacing template parameters by function's parameters
        resultExpression = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(anyTemplate.Parameters[0], collectionPropertyExpression.Body, resultExpression);
        resultExpression = ReplacingExpressionVisitor.Replace(anyTemplate.Parameters[1], anyPredicate, resultExpression);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(resultExpression, entityParam);
    }
}

